# How to make an Image of my Solid State Drive

Tags: ssd

I have installed macOS, Linux and Windows to my MacBook Air. It was hard installing a triple boot system because each of issues with their boot loaders, but now everything works fine.

I want to save the image of my SSD to an external hard drive. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst booted into macOS, you can easily use Disk Utility which comes with macOS to do this. Simply open Disk Utility from your Utilities folder in your Applications folder, choose the source drive from the left hand pane, then click on new image. Expand the file name box and choose a file name for your image, and make sure you select your new drive as the location to store the disk image. In theory, as long as you select the root drive, and not a partition, the image should contain all of your partitions which can then be mounted (as long as you are using a file system macOS supports) and read as well as restored to another drive.

Additionally, if you want to duplicate your SSD to another drive (erasing the other drive in the process) you can choose the destination drive from the left hand pane, and then click the Restore tab. Drag your SSD from the left into the text field which is labelled Source, and drag your destination drive from the left into the box that says Destination.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the program dd to create a disk imgage of an entire disk (including hidden boot partitions etc.)
I use a GParted live CD (linux) to boot from so the disk I want to clone is not in use.

Once booted I go first go to GParted to get the deviceid (/dev/sda or something like that).
Then I open terminal to use dd. Be careful dd will erase your disk if you use "of=/dev/sdX" with the disk you want to copy.

To create an uncompressed img I use: (do not forget to change the drive letter!)

```
dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdb of=/mnt/bla/image1-`date +%d%m%y`.img
```

but you can also zip

```
dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdb | gzip > /mnt/Raspberry/test_dd/image1-`date +%d%m%y`.img.gz
```

"if=" is the source file or disk
"of=" is the destination
if no "of=" is used it will stream it to std. out with you can pipe thru (|)